# How put all fragment of navigation drawer fullscreen?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

i want to display my app in fullscreen mode like with (for each fragments) :

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        requireActivity().window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        requireActivity().window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)

    }
```

but these lines create bug in my app, so how put all of these fragments of my navigation drawer in fullscreen without the lines above ?

What I want is grow the window to delete the black strip :

[Image with black strip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV9M2.png)

EDIT :
Create my own style works

```
<style name="Theme.Generapp.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: what is the bug you encounter?

Comment: Why not read official reference docs? https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive

Comment: @Zain this bug : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66179148/why-my-homefragment-of-my-navigation-drawer-need-after-change-a-textview-to-be

Comment: @emandt Cause i've tried it but doesn't work with nav drawer and HIS fragments :/